# Communication between Android emulator and Fedora 18 VM

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator, fedora

I have problem interconnecting an Android emulator with a Fedora 18 running on a virutal machine. Both run on the same host and I'm trying to create a socket connection between these.
I'read several threads on the issue of interconnecting two emulator instances. I did the changes according to [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#connecting) but it did not work. The linux machine is the server listening for connections from the emulator.
Did anybody have this problem? Or any adivce?

Update: This is the command for listening for incomming connections on the linux VM and sending the `x` variable:

```
x=$(filename); echo $x | nc -l 10.0.2.15 -p 4460.
```

This is the command from the emulator where it stucks when creating the connection:

```
socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4450);
```

I also did this redirection on the VM:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i p2p1 -p tcp --dport 4450 -j REDIRECT --to-port 4460
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code and any error message you are getting?

Comment: Hi Martin. This is the command for listening for incomming connections on the linux VM and sending the x variable: x=$(<filename); echo $x | nc -l 10.0.2.15 -p 4460. This is the command from the emulator where it stucks when creating the connection: socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4450); I also did this redirection on the VM: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i p2p1 -p tcp --dport 4450 -j REDIRECT --to-port 4460. Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with this information.